# How to make Android understand C# objects

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to make an ASP.NET WebService for an Android application. 
Here is my class:

```
public class Student
{
  int StudentID {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
  List<Grade> Grades {get; set;}
}
```

The Grade class is:

```
public class Grade 
{
  int GradeID;
  string Grade;
}
```

When I send this **Student** object using JSON? How can I make Android understand and use that **Student** object? Can you give me some help with that?

Comment: *How to make Android understand C# objects* you need to translate it from C# to java(POCO to POJO translation should be easy as it is only data class) ... and SO is not translation service

Comment: @Selvin Do I really need to do translation? Just parsing the JSON object wouldn't be enough? I couldn't imagine how to parse `Grades`.